# How important is to add GPA on a resume, given years of internships?

Tags: resume

As an undergraduate college student, I have over three years of internship experience -- much of it in my field of study, Computer Science. I also have a year of internship experience in Economics and Marketing. Given this, how important is to include my GPA, and would it be a deal-breaker to potential internship recruiters/employers? Also, what would be a good computer science GPA to have coming out of college? I go to a top-tier university where classes are extremely difficult.

Any and all help/input is appreciated.

Comment: Not directly related - but make sure that when you do quote a GPA, include the maximum score, too. Different institutions grade to different maximums - I've seen grading schemes use 4, 6, 7 and 10.

Answer (score 4):

If it's your first real job out of university, then GPA is likely to be considered.  Internships will help, but it will depend on the organisation and the hiring manager.  Some place more stock in results, especially if you are still studying and the results are recent, while others will be more interested in your internship experience.

A top tier university may help, as far as what would be a "good computer science GPA", the obvious answer would have to be "as high as you can get it."  Beyond that, it's up to the discretion of the hiring manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a nice CGPA, then including it on the resume would just be an icing on the cake, and wouldn't do much harm.

However, if your CGPA is less, then I would advise you not to include it on your resume.(But, if the recruiting manager asks to, then you have to.) Rather, flaunt your projects which you did from your internship experience.

A [similar answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55132/how-to-communicate-to-recruiter-gpa-does-not-reflect-my-abilities/55133#55133) of mine, for a very similar question might help you.

The internship in Economics and Marketing would be an addition, and wouldn't count as mainstream or an important one when you are interviewing for a CS heavy position.

Comment: Depending on teh company, it might be the very thing that sets him above the other CS people. I am far more interested in someone with knowledge outside his field of study than someone who has done nothing but his major.  If the CS job is for a data scientist or in the financial or marketing sector, this is huge plus.

Answer (score 1):

**Only put things on your resume that you'd like to talk about**  From the tone of your post, I'm guessing that your GPA is not stellar, and you don't really want to talk about it.  In that case, leave it off.  Even if it is good, when you get your first job, remove it.

Not having a GPA on the resume may raise a few eye-brows, but most companies will be happy to talk to you about your internships.  A few companies will likely push you to reveal your GPA - if they push tell them the truth, and keep moving.  If a company is stupid enough to dismiss an obviously qualified candidate over a GPA cut-off, then you don't want to work with them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For computer science, GPA is important, but a successful work experience will most likely get you a job.

When you do not put your GPA on a resume, you should focus the content on your multiple internships and work experiences. When the majority of your resume focuses on your successful application of class work future employers see that you will adapt well to a full time workforce.

However, be prepared to give your overall GPA and your major GPA when asked. Be sure to specify the both of these GPA if your overall GPA is low but your major GPA is high. This shows that you know your studies even if you did poorly in your general education classes.