# A recruiter wants to see my transcript and marks but they suck, what to do?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search, hiring-process, recruitment

A received an email from a recruiter at Google, saying they've found me on LinkedIn and that they saw I had a passion for Computer Science and liked my accomplishments. He asked for a recent copy of my resume, a phone number and a unofficial transcript. So we can speak about post graduation plans at Google (I'm soon to graduate from University)

My issue is: my marks suck. Throughout the majority of my school career I battled through some adversity in my family life and that affected my school work (namely time I had to work on assignments and study). Anyways my marks are not good (Cs and Bs). However, I do have a decent GitHub profile, solid internships and I do not believe my marks are a fair representation of my skills.

At this point is there even a point in replying and sending him my transcript? Is there anyway I pass his initial screen?

Comment: There's a reason they're asking for a resume in addition to the transcript, right? Use that wisely.

Comment: Google is contacting graduates on LinkedIn based on a passion for CS? I would think they get more application requests than even they know how to handle.

Comment: @JeffO I was surprised myself.

Comment: Possible dup of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/55132/17890

Comment: @JeffO I think you missed "and liked my accomplishments". It's more likely that the OP made significant contributions on GitHub and/or interned successfully at high-profile companies that brought him on their radar. Most likely OP was referred to them by a friend/colleague/manager.

Comment: @Lilienthal - The OP was surprised as well.

Comment: @JeffO I have also been contacted by a "recruiter from google".  There are multiple reasons by they get so many application requests.  One is that they put tremendous pressure on their recruiters to pump up the volume of applications.  Being solicited from google does not mean that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your resume should highlight your strong points, this is one case when I think the best thing is to get out in front of the bad news. I recommend addressing the issue when your reply. Something like this:

> Dear Google
>
> Here is my resume and transcript, as requested. You will notice that my grades are mostly B and C. However I do not believe that these grades reflect the work i am truly capable of. During my time at school I [insert explanation here]. I believe [course I took when I wasn't under stress] and my GitHub profile better reflect my capabilities.
>
> Yours errorreplicating

The worst case is that they don't read it, and you are no worse off. The best case is that they cut you some slack and decide to interview you despite your grades (or that they didn't care about the grades anyway).

Answer (score 8):

Until you've been out in the working world for a while, everyone is going to want to see your school history. Get used to it, and work on finding good explanations for why your grades don't reflect what you're capable of. Your resume is one place to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 5):

As seen from the other side, when I am checking someone who we are interested in hiring, I mostly check extracurricular activities, like StackOverflow, GitHub, participation in Open Source etc.

The combination of bad marks and high other activity is interesting enough to do some more checking. For example, we use a math-quiz to measure some of the analytical ability. That is not about your effectiveness at getting good marks, but more about general and smart problem solving. Which we rate highly.

So I would not hesitate and just send the grades, accompanied by your resume, which highlights the stuff you did well.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when I was searching for work. I don't know your personal situation, but I had a solid explanation for why I had bad grades, and was able to show that after taking some time to address it, I turned that around and had a GPA over 3.5 my last few terms in school.

As has been suggested in other answers, use your resume to highlight the other accomplishments that show your grades don't paint the whole picture of your capabilities and accomplishments. If they give you the opportunity to write a cover letter, you might quickly address the poor grades, but don't dwell on them; the cover letter should talk about reasons why they should hire you, not be an argument against the reasons why not.

For future applications, I would also leave out your GPA from your resume. Obviously still list your degree and graduation date, but there's no need to put something that you're not proud of right in front of them. If they need it, they'll request it, but at least it won't be the first thing they see about you.

Lastly, you lose almost nothing by sending him the transcript and resume. Maybe they're okay with your grades.  Maybe not. But if they aren't, all that happens is you don't get the interview or the job. If there's a position you want, go ahead and apply. Let the company tell you they don't want you for it. No one has ever thought "Well, this guy isn't great, but he applied, so I guess we *have* to hire him."